# Disable logging only for specific call to Spring Boot Repository method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, logging, error-handling

**Context:** I've implemented a Spring Boot `JpaRepostory` that stores an `Entity` with a column that has a unique constraint. The best way I've found to handle when a user tries to write an entry that already exists (a perfectly normal and expected operation) is to wrap the repository call in a `try/catch` block and swallow the exception. This actually works perfectly. However..

**Problem:** The `JpaRepository` calls that violate the unique constraint log a ton of warnings/errors, which clutters up the console. This scenario is expected and handled, so I don't want the repository to log the warnings/errors.

**Question:** How can I turn off logging just for one specific method call (repository.save)?

The Entity:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    public Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The Repository:

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> { };
```

The Service:

```java
@Service
public class ProductService {

    private final ProductRepository repository;

    public ProductService(ProductRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Sentence addProduct(String name) {
        try {
            // this call will throw an exception and log the error if a Product with name already exists
            // I'd like to disable the logging for this one call only
            repository.save(new Product(name));
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            // handle error here and swallow the exception
        }
    }
```

The undesired logs generated by the call to `repository.save` (repeated thousands of times):

```
insert into product (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-200]
2020-08-01 19:41:18.342  WARN 8320 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2020-08-01 19:41:18.342 ERROR 8320 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.UK_Q48233U3FH44JLOTUJWMDQ967_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.PRODUCT(PRODUCT) VALUES 1674"; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn off hibernate logging for a specific method, however, you can turn off hibernate error logging and maintain the rest of spring logging by adding this to your application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=OFF
```